# Clojure java class casting

Tags: clojure

Is it possible to cast in clojure with java style?
This is java code which I want to implement in clojure:

```java
public class JavaSoundRecorder {
    // the line from which audio data is captured
    TargetDataLine line;
    /**
     * Captures the sound and record into a WAV file
     */
    void start() {
        try {
            AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(16000, 8,
                2, true, true);
            DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, format);
            System.out.println(AudioSystem.isLineSupported(info));
            // checks if system supports the data line
            if (!AudioSystem.isLineSupported(info)) {
                System.out.println("Line not supported");
                System.exit(0);
            }
            
            //line = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
            line = AudioSystem.getTargetDataLine(format);
            line.open(format);
            line.start();   // start capturing

            System.out.println("Start capturing...");

            AudioInputStream ais = new AudioInputStream(line);

            System.out.println("Start recording...");

            // start recording
            AudioSystem.write(ais, AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE, new File("RecordAudio.wav"));

        } catch (LineUnavailableException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Closes the target data line to finish capturing and recording
     */
    void finish() {
        line.stop();
        line.close();
        System.out.println("Finished");
    }

    /**
     * Entry to run the program
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final JavaSoundRecorder recorder = new JavaSoundRecorder();

        // creates a new thread that waits for a specified
        // of time before stopping
        Thread stopper = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(6000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                recorder.finish();
            }
        });

        stopper.start();

        // start recording
        recorder.start();
    }
}
```

And this is what I made in clojure

```clj
    (def audioformat (new javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat 16000 8 2 true true))
    (def info (new javax.sound.sampled.DataLine$Info javax.sound.sampled.TargetDataLine audioformat))
    (if (not= (javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem/isLineSupported info))(print "dataline not supported")(print "ok lets start\n"))
    (def line (javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem/getTargetDataLine audioformat))
    (.open line audioformat)
```

are there any solutions?

Comment: what does `(type TargetDataLine)` return?

Comment: "user=> 
(type javax.sound.sampled.TargetDataLine)
java.lang.Class" is it what are you asked for?

Comment: what is your info object? am trying to reproduce but i need a valid info to start with and i'm not familiar with javax.sound.*.

Comment: (def audioformat (new javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat 16000 8 2 true true))
(def info (new javax.sound.sampled.DataLine$Info javax.sound.sampled.TargetDataLine audioformat))
(if (not= (javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem/isLineSupported info))(print "dataline not supported")(print "ok lets start\n"))
(def line (javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem/getTargetDataLine audioformat))
(.open line audioformat)     line should be TargetDataLine, but it's still AbstractDataLine

Comment: Could you edit your question to show both (1) Java code that does what you want _and_ works and (2) the Clojure code that you have that does not work? Then I bet those not familiar with javax.sound can help you.

Comment: Where we were going with (type line) is that if you try (supers (type line)) you will see the superclasses and interfaces that it supports. On my machine, the concrete type of line is com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectTDL. (supers (type line)) gives quite a few classes, amongst them TargetDataLine. Happily, the open then fails with IllegalArgumentException Can't call public method of non-public class: public final void com.sun.media.sound.AbstractDataLine.open(javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat) throws javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException... sigh. Probably giving up here, sorry.

Comment: Does Clojure support casting ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this issue was explained rather well on the Clojure group here:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/clojure/SNcT6d-TTaQ

You should not need to do the cast (see the discussion in the comments about the super types of the object we have), however you will need to type hint the invocation of open:

```
(.open ^javax.sound.sampled.TargetDataLine line audioformat)
```

Remember that java casts don't really do very much (not like C++ where a cast might completely transform an underlying object).

I am not sure what this code is supposed to do, so I don't know whether it has worked or not. Certainly, I can now run your example without error.

Comment: Can i ask you one more question? How can i access AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE in clojure?

Comment: oh, i've found (javax.sound.sampled.AudioFileFormat$Type/WAVE)

Comment: `#^Foo` is a *very* old syntax, which has been deprecated for years. New code should use just `^Foo` instead.

Comment: @amalloy I did wonder but it was after 11 o'clock and I was waaaaaayyy over my quota of investigation for the evening.